# How to detect if a class or method name have multiple words?

Tags: php, zend-framework

Similar questions have been asked before but this one is different.

I am using Zend Framework 1.12 and I need to check how many words a class or method name contains.

```
I.e. "helloWorld" contains 2 words and "hello" contains 1 word.
```

Right now this is what I am doing.

```
$inflector = new Zend_Filter_Inflector(':class');
$inflector->setRules(array(
     ':class' => array('Word_CamelCaseToUnderscore')
));
//This will return Hello_World
$className = ucfirst($inflector->filter(array('class' => $className))); 

$names = explode("_", $className);
if(count($names) > 1){
   echo 'multiple words';
} else {
   echo 'single word';
}
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like your solution.
For fun I can propose to create your own filter.
In my library `Doydoytools` I create this filter `Doydoytools/Filter/Word/CounterWords.php`:

```
class Doydoytools_Filter_Word_CounterWords extends Zend_Filter_Word_CamelCaseToUnderscore
{
    public function filter($value)
    {
        return count(explode($this->_separator, parent::filter($value)));
    }
}
```

So for the class `Application_Plugin_PSession`

```
$inflector = new Zend_Filter_Inflector(':class');
$inflector->setRules(array(':class' => array(new Doydoytools_Filter_Word_CounterWords())));
$count = $inflector->filter(array('class' => __CLASS__));
```

The result is `4` With your methode the name is `Application_Plugin_P_Session`

Answer (score 0):

I writed code like this:

```
function getMethodByField( $field )
    {
        $result = '';
        if( !empty($field) ) {
            $method = '';
            $strMethodArr = explode('_', $field);
            foreach( $strMethodArr as $str ) {
                $method .= ucfirst( $str );
            }
            $result = $method;
        }
        return $result;

    }
```

Comment: This is not what I have asked in my question.

Comment: For calculate count of words maybe use the php function [preg_match](http://ua2.php.net/preg_match) .
But for this will be pattern with uppercase character search.

Comment: I am aware of that. My current solution is better then that. I want to improve this further.